# Анимация смены чисел

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Каким образом реализуется подобная анимация смены чисел? (картинка - пример).

Не нужен код - сам напишу. Просто хочется понять каким образом это можно сделать.

Стандартные эффекты анимации попробовал практически все, но всё не то.

[пример http://i.xalma.ru/u/i/15/06/23/1/0kSHkr.jpg](http://i.xalma.ru/u/i/15/06/23/1/0kSHkr.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант решения с использованием двух элементов (`.current` и `.next`), расположенных внутри контейнера с `overflow: hidden`, CSS свойства `margin-top` и метода `.animate()`:

```js
var $curElement = $(".number .current");
var $nextElement = $(".number .next");
var height = $curElement.height();
$(".number").css("height", height);
var duration = 1500;
var delay = 500;

var counter = 0;
(function animation() {
    $curElement.text(counter).css("margin-top", 0);
    counter = (counter + 1) % 10;
    $nextElement.text(counter).css("margin-top", height);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $curElement.animate({ "margin-top": (-height) + "px" }, duration, animation);
        $nextElement.animate({ "margin-top": 0 }, duration);
    }, delay);
})();
```

```css
.number {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px;
}

.next {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="number">
    <div class="current">0</div>
    <div class="next"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```